# How to force repeater to render div

Tags: asp.net

suppose i am working with repeater like

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" >
 <ItemTemplate>
 <div>my content 1 </div>
 <div>my content 2 </div>
 <div>my content 3 </div>

 <div>my content 4 </div>
 <div>my content 5 </div>
 <div>my content 6 </div>

 <div>my content 7 </div>
 <div>my content 8 </div>
 <div>my content 9 </div>

 </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:Repeater>
```

what code i need to plugin in my code behind that repeater render div instead of span or table. is it at all possible...please let me know. thanks

Comment: A repeater does not render at all, only the content will be rendered. So i don't understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A repeater will only render what you tell it to render, it doesn't add additional HTML to the page like a GridView or a DataView would.

You can control what is rendered around the items by using a HeaderTemplate and a FooterTemplate.

I'm not 100% certain what you're asking